# Sort directories by max depth

Tags: linux, sorting

How can I sort directories by max depth in my bash script

```
START=/home
echo "Root directory: $START"
DIRS=$(find "$START" -type d)
```

Now I want to sort my direcories

For example:

My directories before:

```
/home/test/sample    
/home/test2    
/home/test3/sample/sample1    
/home/test4/sample
```

After:

```
/home/test3/sample/sample1    
/home/test/sample    
/home/test4/sample    
/home/test2
```

And how can I count max depth?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703979/sort-files-by-depth-bash

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I need. :)

Answer (score 0):

what order are you trying to sort in?
it seems like you want to sort in the order of which dir has the most subdir's to the dir with the least subdirs is this correct if it is i may be able to help... o and could u explain your overall goal???

add this line du -h --max-depth 3 test3 test test4 test2

if this isnt what your looking for please add more info!

Comment: Ask questions seeking more detail as comments to the original question instead of as an answer.

Comment: Ok very well put advice I'm new to this site and am learning more efficient ways of structuring the data on this site ... Thank you for the tip should i delete it?